# How can I show a widget and all its parent containers?

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk, widget, containers

In my program, there is a point where all widgets are hidden. Is there a simple way to show a widget and all of its parent containers? I am not able to use `show_all()`, because that would show other widgets that I don't want shown. I could go down the containers and show them all, but I would prefer not to if there is a more concise solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than iterating through [`Widget.get_parent`](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/class-gtkwidget.html#method-gtkwidget--get-parent) and `show`ing them all, you can also set the [`no-show-all`](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkWidget.html#GtkWidget--no-show-all) property on the widgets you don't want shown, and call `show_all` on the ancestor.

Comment: Thanks, `get_parent()` is cleaner than `get_children()`. I don't know why I was using `get_children()`. :)